# Setting up Thingsboard development in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, thingsboard

I'm trying to setting up my development thingsboard environment with docker and tried to follow the steps mentioned in the readme file located in `TB_HOME/applications/docker` folder.

As I am going to use Cassandra I updated the same in ENV file and trying to execute the `./docker-install-tb.sh --loadDemo` and results in the error when trying to install tbnode.

> Creating docker_cassandra_1 ... done
>
> Creating docker_redis_1     ... done
>   Pulling tb1 (thingsboard/tb-node:latest)...
>   ......
>
> Starting ThingsBoard Installation...
>   Installing DataBase schema for entities...
>   Installing Cassandra DataBase schema part: schema-entities.cql
>   Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: 'install.data_dir' property value is not a valid directory!
>           at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.InstallScripts.getDataDir(InstallScripts.java:88)
>           at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.CassandraAbstractDatabaseSchemaService.createDatabaseSchema(CassandraAbstractDatabaseSchemaService.java:47)
>           at org.thingsboard.server.install.ThingsboardInstallService.performInstall(ThingsboardInstallService.java:140)
>           at org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication.main(ThingsboardInstallApplication.java:43)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:521)
>   Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
>   To enable GC log rotation, use -Xloggc: -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=
>   where num_of_file > 0
>   GC log rotation is turned off

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks
Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are trying in Windows environment, please try in Linux(ubuntu) environment , this error should not occur. I could able to bring up the docker container following Readme.md @ \thingsboard\docker folder.

But i could only access thingsboard UI using node Microservice port not using Webui microservice port.